# Why the Riemann Zeta function has nontrivial zeros

Tags: number-theory, roots, zeta-functions, riemann-hypothesis

I know that the Riemann Zeta function has an infinite number of zeros on the critical line $\sigma = 1/2$;

that it is possible to determine how many zeros the Riemann Zeta function has on any interval $[T, T+H]$;

that the Riemann Zeta function is defined:

by improper integral $\zeta(s) = s\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{[x]-x+\frac{1}{2}}{x^{s+1}}}dx$;

or by other improper integral $\Gamma(s)\zeta(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{s-1}dx}{e^x-1}}$

has the first approximate equation $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n\le x}{\frac{1}{n^s}}-\frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s}+\mathcal{O}(x^{-\sigma})$;

and the second approximate equation $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n\le x}{\frac{1}{n^s}}+\chi(s)\sum_{n\le y}{\frac{1}{n^{1-s}}}+\mathcal{O}(x^{-\sigma})+\mathcal{O}(|t|^{1/2-\sigma}y^{\sigma-1})$;

I know how to calculate the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann Zeta function...

But I can't understand why the Riemann Zeta function has nontrivial zeros and why they lie on the critical line $\sigma = 1/2$?

Many thanks for the answers and the link.

Unfortunately, I was hoping to get a non-trivial answer, not the answer "they are", what they are there Hardy proved in 1914.
The main word in my question is "why", i.e. a philosophical question that requires a philosophical answer, i.e. an answer that penetrates into the essence of things.
I expected to get something like the following answer:
Take the second approximate equation, and equate the $x=y=\Big[\sqrt{\frac{t}{2\pi}}\Big]$; then give the sum of $X_n=\frac{1}{n^s}$, $Y_n=\chi(s)\frac{1}{n^{1-s}}$ and the remainder term $R$ vectors,
then for $\sigma=1/2$ we get a mirror-symmetric vector system, which forms a closed polyline at the points of non-trivial zeros.
As is known from analytic geometry, the sum of the vectors that form a closed polyline is zero.

For example,
[root #4525 at $s=0.5+5006.208381106i$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JWSR.jpg)

Comment: Check this for various approaches and answers- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13647/why-does-the-riemann-zeta-function-have-non-trivial-zeros

Comment: Let $\xi(s) = s(1-s)\pi^{-s/2} \Gamma(s/2) \zeta(s)$ then $\xi(s) = \xi(1-s)$ and $\xi(s) = \overline{\xi(\overline{s})}$ and it is entire and its zeros are the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$. So $\xi(1/2+it)$ is real and it has a zero at every sign change. In his book Titchmarsh shows a simple contradiction when assuming $\xi(1/2+it)$ has the same sign for $|t|$ large enough, thus there are infinitely many non-trivial zeros on $\Re(s)=1/2$.

Comment: Also $\xi$ has growth order $e^{|s|^{1/2+\epsilon}}$, so it is not of the form $P(s) e^{f(s)}$ with $P$ a polynomial and $f$ entire, thus it has infinitely many zeros. A little more work shows the increase of $arg \log \zeta(s), s \in [1/2+it, 2+it]$ is $O(\log t)$ so the density of zeros is $arg \Gamma((1/2+iT)/4)+O(\log T) \sim C T \log T$. The next steps are harder (density of zeros on $\Re(s) \ge \sigma > 1/2$, positive proportion of zeros on $\Re(s) = 1/2$).

Comment: I have a beautiful proof that the non-trivial zeros lie on the line $\sigma=\frac12$ but it's too long to fit in a comment.

Comment: Some visualizasions of zeros: [1](http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/1.1568210830.png) and [2](http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/2.1568210847.png).

Comment: what do colors mean, especially blue?

Comment: [3](http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/3.1568218751.png) and [4](http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/4.1568218765.png). Blue is `Im[F]==0`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What is this package and is there a $\chi(s)$ and $arg(\chi(s))$ calculation in it?

Comment: W. Mathematica.